# Clearing Query in TanStack Query V5 - NextJS14 - Dev Environment

Tags: next.js, tanstackreact-query

I have tried chatGPT, here, google, reddit and am still having a problem.

```
"use client";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "@tanstack/react-query";
import NavMenuDesktop from "./NavMenuDesktop";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface UserData {
  user_role?: string | undefined;
}

const Navbar: React.FC = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const user_data: UserData | any = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["user_data"],
  });
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();

  // queryClient.clear();

  const handleLogout = () => {
    console.log("Data before clear", user_data.data)
    queryClient.clear();
    console.log("Data after clear", user_data.data)
    router.push("/");
    console.log("Logout Data", user_data.data)
  };

  console.log('User Data Outside of handleLogout', user_data.data)
```

When I run with queryClient.clear() inside my handleLogout, it does not clear.  In fact, the "User Data Outside of handleLogout" console log is not even returning anything.  When I comment out queryClient.clear();, the query clears right after I login without handleLogout.  I want the handleLogout to clear the query and direct me to "/".